# How much "data" you can put into a string?

Tags: c++, string

As programmers, we work with strings a lot.  Most of the time, I use them without thinking about them too much.  Lately though, I have been using strings to return copious amounts of information from a function with no problem.  My latest example is a binary tree with 10's of 1000's of entries.  I have a recursive function that simply keeps adding to the string with a newline character at the end.  This function gave no trouble.

So is there any kind of "limit" on how many characters you can put in a string or are you only limited by the amount of memory available?

Comment: You may already know this, but just in case: Whatever the limit, it's not AT ALL good practice to use strings as a means of returning arbitrary information. It's not only dirty from a code readability point of view, it's also pretty sub-optimal for most scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The real limit on the size a string object can reach is returned by member max_size.

from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/capacity/).

Link specific to [`max_size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/max_size/)

So yeah, it's implementation-specific.

Comment: @Jerry yeah I was going to edit my comment to reflect as much, but my 5 minute window expired.

Comment: @Jerry good idea:) @Jesse which is usually, but not always, `~0ul`, but of course it's implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

No, the only limit is available contiguous memory. There are no artificial limits imposed on string length; the length of a string is kept in a `size_t` variable, the maximum value of which is the largest addressable byte in the system (be it 8 or 16 or 32 or 64 bit or whatever).

Comment: Yup, it's only limited by the amount of contiguous memory.  Memory is also constrained by operating system limits like Windows's 2GB limit per application on 32-bit systems.

Comment: Actually if we're talking about pure C strings the size of `size_t` doesn't mean a thing, since it just keeps reading until it hits a `\0`. All that matters is that the string *can* be addressed.

Comment: @Dan should I add that to my answer, or does "available memory" include those limitations?

Comment: @Chris I don't think that really has anything to do with the capacity of a string though.

Comment: The implication seemed to be that the length of a string was limited by the capacity of `size_t`, which simply isn't true in the case of a C string.

Comment: Well, it kind of is indirectly, because the largest value of a `size_t` is the largest address, so a string can't have any more characters than that (assuming characters are one byte). But it's not directly tied to `size_t` or anything, so yeah.

Comment: @Seth, hard to say. :)  I don't think clarification hurts any though.  When a string is allocated on the heap, it does need to be contiguous though.

Comment: Side note:  As with any language, if you're concatenating to a large string, it's best to use some type of string builder class that uses a linked list (or something similar) behind the scenes.  Otherwise, you risk of not being able to allocate a large enough contiguous block on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

It's very big but not unlimited though. You can use `string::max_size` to return the maximum number of characters that the string object can hold. Note that the returned value may vary from system to system.